# Unique body count column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to add a body count for each unique person. Each person has multiple data points.

```
df <-  data.frame(PERSON  = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                  Y = c(2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 1))
```

This is what I'd like it to look like:

```
  PERSON Y UNIQ_CT
1      A 2       1
2      A 5       0
3      A 4       0
4      B 1       1
5      B 2       0
6      C 5       1
7      C 3       0
8      C 7       0
9      C 1       0
```

Comment: `transform(df, uniqct = as.integer(!duplicated(Person))`

Comment: I refined my example. There would be multiple points because Y would be different. I don't want to turn from long to wide not do I want to tabulate. What I would like is for each person to have assigned UNIQ_CT == 1 only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use duplicated and negate it:

```
transform(df, uniqct = as.integer(!duplicated(Person)))
```

Comment: That worked well! I have never seen transform() and duplicated() used in such a fashion before. Where did you come across this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is `dplyr` tag to the question here is an option

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(PERSON) %>% 
   mutate(UNIQ_CT = ifelse(row_number( ) == 1, 1, 0))
```